# Trying to test whether an item exists in the array or not and updating the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

What I am trying to do is:
toggleStar is a function used to select an item from a list of JSON object and add it to another list (i.e the Favorite list)

Here I have tried using indexOf though it doesn't seem to work!

Any suggestions/help would be wonderful!

Thanks in advance!

```
$scope.favlist = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("favlist"));
    console.log($scope.favlist);

$scope.toggleStar = function(item) {
      item.star = !item.star;
      console.log(item);

         var favlistcontent = $window.localStorage.getItem("favlist");
         if(typeof favlistcontent !== 'string'){
           $scope.favlist = [];
           $window.localStorage.setItem("favlist",JSON.stringify($scope.favlist));
         }
         $scope.favlist = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("favlist"));
         if( $scope.favlist.indexOf(item) === -1 ) {
         $scope.favlist.push(item);
         $window.localStorage.setItem("favlist",JSON.stringify($scope.favlist));

       } else if( $scope.favlist.indexOf(item) > -1 ){
        console.log("item already exist");

      }

  }
```

Comment: You need to go off an id or something, you are not going to use indexOf with an object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! Could you elaborate an ID or sth?

Comment: I have no idea what is in your object.

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf()` will only work when the array contains the same object reference.

Since the array you are searching in was just created from a json string the object it contains that matches your item is not the same reference.

You will need to iterate through the array and compare ID or other unique identifier to find the matching item

Simple example:

```
var arr =[{foo:"bar"}];
var b = {foo:"bar"};

arr.indexOf(b); // -1 since it isn't the same object reference
```

.

```
var arr2 = []
var x= {foo:"bar"};

arr.push(x);
arr.indexOf(x); // 0 since it is the same object reference
```

Also you can use `angular.equals()` to check for the match in your iteration however you would need to not change `item.star` until you have made the comparison

Comment: Array.indexOf() basically does an '===' operation against the argument and each element of the array.  When the operands to '===' are objects, it's testing "are these the same exact object".  In practice, this is not very useful very often.

Comment: @JohnHascall sure it is. It is used all the time in angular apps to splice arrays to remove items or shift their index

Comment: Thank you! I would give it a go!